# SQL Azure export Data to FTP site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure hosted (web-forms) asp.net website, using Azure SQL for the database.

I need to setup an automatic transfer of some of the data nightly to a specific FTP site.  The data will be in CSV format... so just a basic query, CSV file created, and the file sent via FTP.

My first inclination would be to just create a specific web-page which does the query, creates the file, and sends it out (all in code) - and then schedule this using Azure Scheduler Jobs Collection.... but I'm just wondering if there would be another "best practice" method for doing this such as Azure Data Factory, connectors, etc?

Just wanted to get some input on what road to go down. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first inclination would be to just create a specific web-page which does the query, creates the file, and sends it out (all in code) - and then schedule this using Azure Scheduler Jobs Collection.... but I'm just wondering if there would be another "best practice" method for doing this such as Azure Data Factory, connectors, etc?

Firstly, as you mentioned, you can run a job/task on schedule (Azure Scheduler, Azure WebJobs or Azure Functions can help you achieve it) to request that specific web-page to transfer data from Azure SQL database to FTP server.

Secondly, Azure Logic Apps enable us to use [SQL Database connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) and [FTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp) to access/manage SQL Database and FTP server, you can try to use it. And [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280103/azure-logic-for-getting-data-from-sql-to-ftp) discussed transferring data from SQL database to FTP server using Azure Logic Apps, you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you - I will consider using Logic Apps